# How do I fit a function inside an opening and closing do_shortcode

Tags: shortcode, attachments, pdf

How do I fit a function inside an opening and closing shortcode.

I have this function that displays the post's pdf attachment url

```
$file= get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'teacher-resume-upload' ); 
if ( $file) { foreach ( $file as $attachment_id ) { $full_size = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ); 
printf( '%s', $full_size); } }
```

How would I fit the above code into this...

```
echo do_shortcode( '[pdf]' . $text_to_be_wrapped_in_shortcode . '[/pdf]' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work assuming your trying to pass the URL to the PDF short code

```
$file= get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'teacher-resume-upload' ); 
if ( $file) { 
   foreach ( $file as $attachment_id ) { 
       $full_size = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ); 
       echo do_shortcode( '[pdf]' . $full_size . '[/pdf]' );
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out...

```
<?php $file= get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'teacher-resume-upload' ); $full_size = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );?>
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[pdf]' . $full_size . '[/pdf]' ); ?>
```